# Exif-js command not working in Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, exif, exif-js

I writing a program with Angular and I'm using [exif-js](https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js/tree/master/example)

I'm console logging createDate and it's coming back undefined. I want it to pull the date from the metadata stored on the jpeg file.

I don't understand why createDate is coming back as undefined.

```
.controller('BeforeCtrl', ['$scope', '$upload', '$http', function($scope, $upload, $http) {

$scope.upload = function (files) {
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
              EXIF.getData(file, function() {
              var createDate = EXIF.getTag(this, "DateTimeOriginal");
              console.log(createDate);
              });...
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the image I was using for testing did not have a date stored in the metatags.